# UITabBarController not showing all the tabs

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I've been having a weird issue with the UITabBarController. Here it is:

1. I created a new Single View application
2. I dragged and dropped Tab Bar Controller on to the storyboard which has two initial view controllers.
3. I created two classes for those two view controllers.
4. I dragged another view controller on to the storyboard and connected the UITabBar to this new view controller. So now the tab controller shows three tabs.

So the issue is sometimes the tabbar doesnt show the third tab at all. And sometimes it shows. I've no freakin idea why this is happening. Can anyone please me with this.

Anand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating Tabbar app using  Single View application, create tabbar like this:

Select single view goto Menu Editor-->Embed In --> Select Tab Bar Controller.

Then drag drop your other two viewController. 
Create a realetionShip Segue with viewController clean project it should be working.

Comment: I tried it just now. Still not working. Still displaying the first two controllers only.

Comment: if you didnt do any more work on your project coud you provide sample.

Comment: Here is the layout:
The tab bar controller has 4 tabs now. And yes it shows the first two controllers some times (Controller 1 and Controller 2) and all the controllers some times.
Even if i change the order of tabs like (Controller 3, Controller 4, Controller 1 and Controller 2) It still displays tabs for Controller 1 and Controller 2.

Initial View Controller ---> Tab Bar Controller --> Navigation Controller -- > Controller 1
--> Navigation Controller --> Controller 2
--> Navigation Controller --> Controller 3 
--> Navigation Controller --> Controller 4

Comment: I am sorry if my comment is not readable I dont know how to format the text here. If you dont undestand my comment please let me know.

Comment: I have a question: Can two tab bar controllers share tabs?
In my project: When the user login using the login controller we are checking if the user has full access to the app or not. If he has then i am taking to a tab bar controller which has 4 tabs and if he doesnt have access then i am taking the user to a different tab controller which has only two tabs (Subset of tabs in the first tab bar controller). It looks like what ever tabs in the second tab bar controller are not getting loaded sometimes in the first tab bar controller if the user has full access.

Comment: I see. Sometime xCode can do something like that. Better solution is creating project from the begining. I made a sample project for you. İnitial view is for login view then if user have ful access push t tab1 othervise pushto tab2. But as I understand, you can costumize your tabbar view controller's view controller with code. I will provide sample for that as well later. [Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nn9incfsejuw8cq/tabbarTest.zip)

Comment: I figured out what my issue was. According to Apple "When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller." which was not i was doing. So, i modified my code and made the tab bar controller as the root view controller and now everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to set the title manually after creation for the tab to show up in the TabBarController. I still have no idea why...

```
let salesController = SalesController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
let orderReviewController = OrderReviewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
let accountController = AccountController()

// need to set the title here instead of viewDidLoad() otherwise tab doesn't show up...wtf?
accountController.title = "Account"

viewControllers = [salesController, orderReviewController, accountController]
```